# Previously referenced DLL is still included in build output after removing reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and working on a project that someone else created.  This project had references to several DLLs (directly referencing the DLL), many of which I don't need anymore because of some major design changes.  I've removed the references from my project, but the unneeded DLLs still get put in the build output when building my project, and they get included as detected dependencies in a new Setup project that I created.

Why when I've removed a reference to a DLL does it still get detected as a dependency and get included in the build?  There is nothing in code referencing any of these DLLs, I've made sure of that.  I've also opened the csproj file in a text editor and don't see anything referencing these DLLs that still show up in the build, so what gives?

Comment: try removing that specific dll from your dll library folder and from all bin's, you'll find straight away where it's being used ;)

Comment: Are you doing a Rebuild (or a Clean before you Build)? If not, it might just be left in the output from a previous build.

Comment: Try using a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine where the dependencies are.  This is, of course, assuming that you do still have that dll referenced after doing a clean.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are shared DLLs that are used all over our main applications.  I am revamping an import utility, and didn't want the dependecies on these shared DLLs, so I removed them.  I can delete these specific DLLs form the bin folder and run my executable with absolutely no problem, so I know my application isn't using them at all.

Comment: Could it be transitively dependent through another assembly?

Comment: @Matthew - Well, that's possible, yes.  I'll check into that.  I didn't think about that, but that's probably it.  Although I know if I delete these DLLs in question, I don't have any issues, but in all likelihood you're right.  These DLLs in question used to be directly referenced by my project, so it never occurred to me that they might also be referenced by some other DLL that I left as a reference to my project.

Comment: @Matthew, getting back to this, you were correct that it was transitively dependent through another referenced assembly.  If write this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the project you're building transitively depends on that assembly.

Comment: @Mathew I did not believe in your answer so i created entire replica of project without the unwanted dll . guess what happened !! it's including the dll by default :D . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Build > Clean Solution or Rebuild Solution and it will probably go away.

The output folder doesn't get cleaned when simply building a solution, so any old files are left there until you issue either of the above commands.

Comment: I've done a Clean and Rebuild both, and also manually deleted everything from the bin\Debug and bin\Release folder before building, and it still comes up.

Comment: In that case, something somewhere is referencing the library still.  How many projects are in the solution?  And what language are they?

Comment: There's a single project in the solution and it's a C# Windows Forms application.  I believe Matthew from the comments on the original post might be correct; while I removed direct references to the DLLs that I no longer need, chances are that some DLL that I do still need references one of the ones I don't still need.  To figure that out, I have to look through the projects of the DLLs that I am still referencing and see what they in turn reference.